# Micro-kernel architecture based operating system for desktop users?

Tags: operating-system, microkernel, fuchsia, sel4

Can we have Operating system with micro-kernel architecture targeted on desktop users? I have read here on this website that older micro-kernel can be 50% slower than Monolithic kernel, while later version like L4 were only 2% or 4% slower than the Monolithic kernel. L4 kernel is very famous for its performance.

Why don't we have an operating system based on micro-kernel architecture targeted on desktop users? Can we have such operating systems in future?

Comment: Look at GNU Hurd and its Mach kernel.

Comment: I already said that older micro-kernel can be 50% slower than Monolithic kernel but then mentioned L4 micro kernel.

Comment: "Why don't we have ..." We have. "Can we ..." Yes, as we could already in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Existing OSes like Windows, Linux have a huge ecosystem thus most resources go into them. However, there are projects to micro kernel base system and there's a huge use in special use cases. It takes time and work to create a general purpose OS - and the practical benefit is quite low for most user, as then wont ever notice what OS core they are actually using.

You may give this a try: https://genode.org

Or watch this: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Fuchsia